# How to add new column of total as sum of two columns in UNIX?

Tags: unix, awk

I have a flat file as,

```
physics   chem
10        20
12        12
10        10
```

I want to add a one more column **total marks** which will have total of physics and chem.

Comment: Hi Rex! Welcome. For us to help you, let us know what type of file this is (is it a flat file? a spreadsheet?). How are you writing to the file, are you using a program or a script or something? If you are using a program or script, then could you post the code? Tell us more

Comment: @ChadMcGrath since the question was tagged  with awk and unix, I don't think this is a file with Micro$oft format.

Comment: The awk tag was added after Rex edited the question as he was asked to during my review (you can see this in the edited link). Flat files and spreadsheets aren't specific to Windows, they are generic terms that apply to many platforms, including unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this awk one-line:

```
awk '$0=$0"\t"(NR==1?"total":$1+$2)' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I find @Kent's answer difficult to read. I'd write

```
awk 'NR==1 {val = "total"} NR > 1 {val = $1+$2} {$(++NF) = val; print}' file | column -t
```

Comment: Welcome back to SO! You've been pretty quiet.